# Form Submission issue, how I can get value of ID at end of my URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have following code and I want to submit my Form on click button, Click function is working fine but tell me how I can Assign values of "ID" at the end of my URL as mentioned on the below code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-success").click(function(){
    var ID = $(this).prev('.sendEmail').attr('id');
        alert(ID);
    });
    });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var form = $('#form2'); // contact form
      var submit = $('#submit2');  // submit button
      var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message




      // form submit event
      form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
          url: '//mydomain.com/'+ID, 
          type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
          dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
          data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
          beforeSend: function() {
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
          },
          success: function(data) {
            alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            submit.html('&#10004; Alert Successfully Sent!'); // reset submit button text
          },
          error: function(e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `ID` var global:

```
var ID;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-success").click(function(){
        ID = $(this).prev('.sendEmail').attr('id');
        alert(ID);
    });
});
```

...rest of your code

Or if you combine your document ready calls:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ID;
    $(".btn-success").click(function(){
        ID = $(this).prev('.sendEmail').attr('id');
        alert(ID);
    });

   var form = $('#form2'); // contact form
   var submit = $('#submit2');  // submit button
   var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

   form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

    $.ajax({
      url: '//mydomain.com/'+ID, 
      type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
      dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
      data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert.fadeOut();
        submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
        form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
        submit.html('&#10004; Alert Successfully Sent!'); // reset submit button text
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[This may help you understand more about variable scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: i have a form with multiple same values in loop, 
<input type="hidden" name="expiry_domain">
<input type="hidden" value="sales@mydomain.com" name="email">
<input type="hidden" class="sendEmail" value="mydomain/461" id="461" name="url">
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" id="submit2">Send Expiry Alert!</button>

Comment: @ArslanAli, sorry this would be an extra question - I have answered the one about how to make your ID work.  You should ask a seperate question about your multiple values